# Java Paint if x = location do this else do this

Tags: java, awt

I'm in computer SCI AP and I can't figure out why this isn't working

```
public static void moon(Graphics g) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 550; k+=2) {
        if (k == 550) {     
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(k,50,50,50);
            for(long delay = 1; delay<10000000; delay++);   
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(k,50,50,50); 
            k = 0;
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(k,50,50,50);
            for(long delay = 1; delay<10000000; delay++);   
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(k,50,50,50); 
        }
    }
}
```

So basically is will make the black oval move across the screen then when `k` = 550 it will make the blue one go across the screen.. But it doesn't do that it just moves the black one then after it hits 550 it stops.. and the blue one doesn't come up.

Comment: For your sake as well as ours, please indent code blocks in a consistent and logical way.  More meaningful attribute names could not hurt either.

Comment: `for(long delay = 1; delay<10000000; delay++);`  Will most likely be optimized out.  This is entirely the wrong approach to custom painting.  See the [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) lesson of the Java Tutorial for working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never reaches k = 550.
The condition in the `for` loop is `k < 550`. Make it `k <= 550` and it should work.

However, you may not see it happen, because you're using `for(long delay = 1; delay<10000000; delay++);` to delay - this is not a very reliable way to delay.

To see things happen more reliably, try using [Thread.sleep(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).
For the record, I believe there are some arguments against using `Thread.sleep(long)` in general, but in this case it should suffice.

While I'm at it, the `k = 0` assignment is superfluous, it's even bad style. You should not assign to a loop variable *inside* the loop. If the loop is entered again, the `for (int k=0` part will take care of setting k to 0.

HTH

Comment: This one works, but it does not go to the blue one it still displays the same black one.

Answer (score 3):

You will always enter the else path, because your for loop counts from 0 to 549, so k will never be equal to 550.

Comment: Also I think python should be tought, so people are forced to do proper indenting.

Comment: auto-indent button would be a better idea... oooops, not for python :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int k = 0; k < 550; k+=2)
```

will loop but k will not enter the loop with the value of 550 so your if statement will not be executed at all

use this

```
for(int k = 0; k <= 550; k+=2)
```

Comment: This one works, but it does not go to the blue one it still displays the same black one.

Answer (score 0):

`k` will never be 550, because your expression is `k < 550`.

Either change it to `k <= 550` or move the `550` part outside of the loop entirely.

IMO it doesn't really belong in the loop if it only happens once and the other *n* hundred times it doesn't. Better to have an inner loop for all the rest, and an outer loop that makes it run forever rather than modifying the loop variable.

Comment: This one works, but it does not go to the blue one it still displays the same black one.