# Java Paint for loop issue

Tags: java, graphics

```
class background {
    public static void moon(Graphics g) {
        int k2 = 0;
        int k3 = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k <= 550; k+=2) {
            if (k2 == 550) {
                for (k2 = 550; k3 <= 550; k3+=2) {
                    k = 0;
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g.fillOval(k3,50,50,50);
                    for(long delay = 1; delay<1000000; delay++);    
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    g.fillOval(k3,50,50,50);
                    k2 = 0;
                }   
            } else {
                k2+=2;
                k3=0;
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillOval(k,50,50,50);
                for(long delay = 1; delay<1000000; delay++);    
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillOval(k,50,50,50); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my problem: in the applet it will show the black ball go across, then the blue ball, then the black ball. Then it won't show anything else. What I want is it to just continue to loop black, blue, black, blue, and just keep going on and on.

Comment: You don't have a while loop for starters...meaning that even if the code works, it will only cycle once.

Comment: Thanks max.. Please make this a reply so i can Thumbs up your answer

Comment: Still no SSCCE, still forcing other people to clean up your code to the point it is readable, still trying to [draw a moon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386779/java-paint-if-x-location-do-this-else-do-this) yet it is no longer homework (apparently).  ..Interesting, but not enough to draw me in to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you were just lacking a while loop to keep you going. Something like...

```
while(true){

stuffyouwanttodo();

}
```

Would be what you're looking for.